# Microsoft Graph API Paging interface with python and html

Tags: python, html, flask, pagination, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I am trying to use the @odata.nextLink to paginate the data I retrieve from graph API. I will need some sort of arrows on html to go back and forth, so i will have to maybe create some function with flask on python code to use the @odata.nextLink value that is in the json file, so it loads the next group of data. What I have been trying to do is something like this but my "Next" function will just retrieve the second group of data, it is missing the functionality for going back and also I created a second html file to display this next chunk of data which is pointless. I would like you guys to give me an idea of how make this work.

**Python Code:**

```
import base64
import mimetypes
import os
import pprint
import uuid

import flask
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth
from flask import request

import config

APP = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='static/templates')
APP.debug = True
APP.secret_key = 'development'
OAUTH = OAuth(APP)
MSGRAPH = OAUTH.remote_app(
    'microsoft',
    consumer_key=config.CLIENT_ID,
    consumer_secret=config.CLIENT_SECRET,
    request_token_params={'scope': config.SCOPES},
    base_url=config.RESOURCE + config.API_VERSION + '/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url=config.AUTHORITY_URL + config.TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
    authorize_url=config.AUTHORITY_URL + config.AUTH_ENDPOINT)

@APP.route('/')
def homepage():
    """Render the home page."""
    return flask.render_template('homepage.html')

@APP.route('/login')
def login():
    """Prompt user to authenticate."""
    flask.session['state'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    print(config.REDIRECT_URI)
    return MSGRAPH.authorize(callback=config.REDIRECT_URI, state=flask.session['state'])

@APP.route('/login/authorized')
def authorized():
    """Handler for the application's Redirect Uri."""
    if str(flask.session['state']) != str(flask.request.args['state']):
        raise Exception('state returned to redirect URL does not match!')
    response = MSGRAPH.authorized_response()
    flask.session['access_token'] = response['access_token']
    print(flask.session['access_token'])
    return  flask.redirect('/query')



@MSGRAPH.tokengetter
def get_token():
    """Called by flask_oauthlib.client to retrieve current access token."""
    return (flask.session.get('access_token'), '')

def request_headers(headers=None):
    """Return dictionary of default HTTP headers for Graph API calls.
    Optional argument is other headers to merge/override defaults."""
    default_headers = {'SdkVersion': 'sample-python-flask',
                       'x-client-SKU': 'sample-python-flask',
                       'client-request-id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
                       'return-client-request-id': 'true'}
    if headers:
        default_headers.update(headers)
    return default_headers


@APP.route('/query')
def query():
    # query = "groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'C')"
    query = "groups/?$expand=members"

    result = MSGRAPH.get(query, headers=request_headers()).data

    return flask.render_template('query.html',result=result, query=query)

@APP.route('/next')
def next():

    query = "groups/?$expand=members"
    result = MSGRAPH.get(query, headers=request_headers()).data
    nextResult = MSGRAPH.get(result['@odata.nextLink'], headers=request_headers()).data

    return flask.render_template('query_2.html', result=nextResult, query=query)
# Last Group Was: APP_EZSHARE_CO-O0004

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.run()
```

**HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
See LICENSE in the source repository root for complete license information. -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>{{ sample }} sample</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/site.css?version=1.28" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container homepage-container">
            <div>
                <h1 style="text-align: center">Active Directory Viewer</h1>




                <div>
                    <!--<h1>Result</h1>-->
                    <table border="1px solid black">
                    <tr>
                        <!--<th>ID</th>-->
                        <th>Group Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <!--<th>Users</th>-->
                    </tr>

                    {% for gd in result.value %}
                    <tr style="background-color: green; color: white">
                        <!--<td>{{ gd.id }}</td>-->
                        <td>{{ gd.displayName }}</td><!-- TRYING TO ACCESS THE GROUP DISPLAYNAME-->
                        <td>{{ gd.description }}</td>
                    </tr>

                    {% for mem in gd.members %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ mem.displayName }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}

                    {% endfor %}
                    </table>

                    <a href="/next"><input type="button" value="Next"></a>
                    <!--{{ result }}-->
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, as you reference, the Microsoft Graph API's pagination mechanism doesn't provide bi-directional pagination, I wouldn't use it to provide such a feature to users. Instead, I'd use the [`$skip`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#skip-parameter) parameter. Indeed, as that article notes:

> Some Microsoft Graph APIs, like Outlook Mail and Calendars (message, event, and calendar), use `$skip` to implement paging.

I also can't find any guarantees from Microsoft about the durability of the [`$skipToken`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#skiptoken-parameter) parameter used in the `@odata.nextLink` value for some Graph APIs, so I'd be wary of using it in a user-facing context where it's possible it could expire pretty quickly (in this or future iterations of the current major version of the API).

If you simply use the `$skip` parameter to provide pagination, the format of the resulting JSON will be the same, so you should be able to use the same HTML template for the first and all subsequent pages. I'd have a single `/query` route (and not a `/next` route) that simply accepts an optional parameter named something like `skip`.

Comment: You were right talking about the paging durability with using the value inside the @odata.nextLink, it lasted me for like 13 pages and when i clicked again the next, it got me an error back. Do you think with skip i would be able to implement the back button? If you know how please let me know. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, you can implement a back button using `$skip`. If, for example, there are 10 records per page and the user is on the third page (that is, the records returned for `$skip=20`), then the user would be served the records returned for `$skip=10` when they hit the back button.

Note that there is the possibility that the data changes while the user is paginating, changing which records show up in which pages. Something to consider that may or may not be acceptable for your use case.

Comment: Got it, so it would be like increasing or decreasing the $skip's value depending on where the user wants to move. Hmm i do not think there is gonna be a problem according to the use case, because i want to also implement a push notificator when the data changes. Fortunately this api provides that posibility.

Comment: Yes indeed. Good luck!